# How to Append the text file using stored value variable in Scala

Tags: scala, text-files

I want to append line at end of text file without using the loop or Array. I tried following code it gives me an error.

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._
var ValueOne:Int=15
var ValueTwo:Int=16
var ValueThree:Int=20
val fw = new FileWriter("Text File", true) ; fw.write(ValueOne.toString,ValueTwo.toString,ValueThree.toString) ;
fw.flush
fw.close()
```

here is the error

```
error:overloaded method value write with alternatives:
(x$1: String,x$2: Int,x$3: Int)Unit <and>
 (x$1: Array[Char],x$2: Int,x$3: Int)Unit
 cannot be applied to (String, String, String)
```

I wanted to write the output in this format in text file:

```
11,92,20 
19,21,34
15,16,20
```

Anybody can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-java.lang.String-) takes one string as an argument, so you need to combine the values into a string:

```
fw.write( Seq(ValueOne, ValueTwo, ValueThree).mkString(",") )
```

You can do it using the [`mkString`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@mkString(sep:String):String) method.